# I've never been to/in a real forest

Tags: prepositions

A native speaker asked "Have you ever been **IN** a real forest?"

I said "No, I've never been **TO** a real forest."

Why did he say 'in' instead of 'to?' Do both mean the same thing?

Comment: 'Have you ever been **in** a real forest' means 'have you ever **stayed** in a real forest' whereas the one with 'to' means 'have you ever **visited**.....'.

Comment: But what is a "real forest".  Ashdown forest (home of Winnie-the-pooh) is mostly open heathland. Forests don't have to be wooded.

Answer (score 1):

They have essentially the same meaning, but there is a subtle difference. Being *in* a forest means that you are actually inside the forest, like going under the trees etc. Going *to* a forest could mean you got close to a forest without actually going inside. As Void mentioned "in" also carries the connotation that you spent some time in the forest, whereas "to" naturally includes both simply visiting and spending time in the forest. This is a difference in connotation only; it's not incorrect to use "in" if you only spent a brief time in the forest.

Despite having the essentially same meaning, "been to" is slightly more natural in this context than "been in". Regarding places we normally tend to use "to" instead of "in", unless you actually want to make use of the subtle difference in meaning.